# AppleScript multiword element name

Tags: applescript

## Problem

From AppleScript, I want to visit the list of all chats in an Adium chat window, looking for a particular chat name, but it doesn't work:

Adium's Dictionary includes:
 [S] Adium > [C] application > [E] chat window

What I think I want to do is

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell application "Adium" to activate
  repeat with tw in chat windows of process "Adium"
    repeat with ch in chats of tw
      if name of ch is "nickserv" then
        -- do some stuff
      end if
    end repeat
  end repeat
end tell
```

But I get "Syntax Error: Expected end of line but found plural class name" at the reference to "chat windows".

## Answer (from responses, and further work)

Getting the window list directly from the process, rather than from "System Events" avoids the choke at "plural class name":

```
tell application "System Events"
  repeat with tw in chat windows of process "Adium"
    -- is a syntax error: you're not getting an Adium window, it's a SysEvents window

tell application "Adium"
  repeat with tw in chat windows
    -- works
```

However, the properties of a window (or chat window) as known to "System Events" are very different from those for a window known to Adium. What I'm actually doing is positioning the window on screen. With a System Events window, I do something like this:

```
set position of tw to {440, 1600}
set size of tw to {993, 578}
```

... but with a direct Adium window, it's

```
set bounds of tw to {440, 1600, 440+993, 1600+578}
```

Sprinkling "properties tw" about, as more or less hinted in the comments by Lauri Ranta, reveals these differences.

## Other Answer

I also found that

```
repeat with tw in (chat windows) of process "Adium"
```

gets past the "multiword element name" issue, though not the "windows have different properties" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use System Events for this. I assume "Adium" is scriptable so you can talk directly to the application (open "Adium.app" with "AppleScript-Editor.app" to see if it is so).

```
tell application "Adium"
 activate

 -- do stuff

end tell
```

I don't use Adium so I can't tell if the rest of the script is ok, but for sure it would look more like this:

```
    tell application "Adium"
     activate

     repeat with tw in chat windows
      repeat with ch in chats of tw

       if name of ch is "nickserv" then
         -- do some stuff
       end if

      end repeat
     end repeat

    end tell
```

Comment: That gets past the syntax error, but leaves me with deeper errors. Still, this answers the question I posed.

Comment: Thank You for the feedback. Check out Adium's Scripting Dictionary to figure out the appropriate syntax for your script. You can do that in AppleScript-Editor (…) Good Luck!

Comment: I had the Adium dictionary open from the first. What tripped me up, in that neighborhood, was that a "window" as returned by Adium is not the same as a "window" returned by System Events. Rookie error.

Answer (score 1):

chat and chat window elements are contained by the application element:

```
tell application "Adium"
    properties of chat "nickserv"
    --chat window "nickserv"
end tell
```

Comment: That gets past the syntax error, but leaves me with deeper errors. Still, this answers the question I posed.